# Let my web service asmx be added as service reference to other asp project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

I've created a simple web service (.asmx) i can access the service via web browser. I can access it and the method was working fine. However when i tried to add it up as a service reference to one of test projects (I'm doing this because it was it needs to do to be added as a service reference to other project) It returns an error like this :

[image]

Did i missed out something on web configuration?or in my codes?

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SSOCheckAuthentication : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string AuthenticationCheck(string artifact)
    {
        return "test string";
    }
```

Config files :

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>

<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx"
    type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
     validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try adding it as a web reference instead of service reference

Comment: Which address did you enter into the add reference dialog?